# Put request IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I try to update a object in the database trough a API call. I do this action with a PUT request. A Post request was already made and is working fine. I thought it is just copy paste...

The API part works fine because if I execute the following curl command than it updates the row I wanted in the database

```
$ curl -H 'Accept: application/json' -i -X PUT -d 'UserLogin=Ub0D&EndDate=2014-01-17 00:00:00.0000000&Sport=Fietsen&Distance=1000&Duration=10&Achieved=true&DateCreated=2015-05-09 12:01:00.000000' http://localhost:8089/api/goal/ub0d -k -u ub0d:test123
```

But now the part in swift gives me a bad request error (400)...
This is my code

```
    var url : NSURL
    url = NSURL(string: _apiUrl + connectToApi(apiCall) + String("\(AccountRepository.Instance.getCurrentUserName())"))!

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    if postString != nil {

        let postData : NSData = ("UserLogin=Ub0D&EndDate=2014-01-1700:00:00.0000000&Sport=Fietsen&Distance=1000&Duration=10&Achieved=true&DateCreated=2014-01-1700:00:00.0000000").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        // create the request
        request.HTTPMethod = "PUT"
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.HTTPBody = postData
    }
    var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)!
```

I'm really stuck on it:(

Comment: You've taken spaces out of the timestamps. You should also percent escape the body. And as Sulthan says, you only want the `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and remove the `Content-Type` of `application/json`.

Comment: Also, your `curl` command specifies `-u`; have you implemented the authentication delegate methods in your delegate? What sort of authentication is the server actually performing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You request can't have two different content types at the same time:

```
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")
```

The data you are sending are obviously not JSON, so I guess you want only

```
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
```

and remove the `"application/json"` line.

There is also a difference between your date formats:

**CURL**

```
EndDate=2014-01-17 00:00:00.0000000
```

**Swift**

```
EndDate=2014-01-1700:00:00.0000000
```

Note the missing space between date and time, probably should be URL encoded (`+`):

```
EndDate=2014-01-17+00:00:00.0000000
```

In general, most REST APIs send error messages in response body, so it is always good to log the response for failed requests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I removed both "setvalues" but that makes no difference. I also tryed to remove the .00000 behind the datetimes.

I don't get it because through the command line it works

Comment: @troncki Check what message you are getting with that 400 code. If the API is any good, it should tell you what's wrong with your request.

Comment: This is what the response prints. 
`{ status code: 400, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    "Content-Length" = 212;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Sat, 09 May 2015 17:45:36 GMT";
    Expires = "-1";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
}`
The only thing which are different is the content lenght, access control and content-type

Comment: @troncki Print the response body, it probably contains the error message.

Comment: I've finally got the message, thanks for that:) The error message is about the dates in the string. How can i pass them succesfully? The weird thing is that I use the same string to POST the values and I just want to update now

Comment: Thanks!! Finally after a long time the api PUT request is succesful executed :) Actually I formatted the date as following and that worked for me `stringToDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000"`